# How to rename a src_key to append a timestamp files?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Im working on a python lambda that is transferring files from one bucket to another. After the file is copied to the other bucket, Im needing to move that file into a "processed" folder and append a time stamp to the file.

Here is the main part of the code

```
import datetime

def handler(event, context):
    LOGGER.info(f'Event structure: {event}')
    LOGGER.info(f'DST_BUCKET: {DST_BUCKET}')

    for record in event['Records']:
        src_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        src_key = record['s3']['object']['key']

        copy_source = {
                    'Bucket': src_bucket,
                    'Key': src_key
                        }
        LOGGER.info(f'copy_source: {copy_source}')
        bucket = s3.Bucket(DST_BUCKET)
        LOGGER.info(f'bucket: {bucket}')

        bucket.copy(copy_source, src_key)

        try:
            #Check file
            s3.Object(DST_BUCKET, src_key).load()
            LOGGER.info(f"File {src_key} uploaded to Bucket {DST_BUCKET}")

            src_bucket = s3.Bucket('<bucketNamehere>')

            # this is where Im setting the date
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[4]+data[5],'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

            src_bucket.copy(copy_source, 'processed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1] + dt)
            LOGGER.info(f"File {src_key} processed")

    
        except Exception as e:
            return {"error":str(e)}

    return {'status': 'ok'}
```

I tried this but it doesnt work

```
  dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[4]+data[5],'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
  src_bucket.copy(copy_source, 'processed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1] + dt)`
```

Just copies over `src_key` but doesn't actually append the date to the file(s). What Im trying to get outputted is `filename-YYYMMDDHHMSS.<fileextension>`

Comment: Are you saying that code creates a file in `processed/` ?  It should be throwing an exception.

Comment: Initially when I ran it all I see is "src_key" in processed folder. I then looked in cloudwatch and saw a bunch of errors.

Comment: Those errors should point out what's wrong, namely, you need to combine two strings, not a string and a non-string object, with something like `'processed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1] + dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")`

Comment: When I do that it will not append the timestamp before the file extension. So basically, it just puts it after the extension -> `test.docx20230315-160845`

Comment: `timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
  src_bucket_outbound.copy(copy_source, 'processed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1] + timestr)` This is what im using for the above , but its still appending to the wrong place.

Comment: You are saying you need "to move that file into a 'processed' folder", but you are copying the file.  Could you please clarify how many copies of the object you want to have and where.  Incidentally, why do you need to change the object key?  Can you just add a tag 'processed'='timestamp'?

Comment: And also clarify what you expect the final filename itself to be.  It's not clear, since you're now contradicting yourself.

Comment: The best way to debug this situation is to `print` the string and see for yourself what command is being sent to AWS. So, before copying the file, use `print('processed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1] + dt).` You might be surprised at the result! (I'm particularly suspicious of "`data[4]+data[5]`")

Comment: I resolved issue, but had to basically rewrite the whole filename. Not fun.